# Issue with src_snowflakedb(): 'src_sql' is not an exported object

Tags: r, jdbc, dplyr, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use `dplyr` with a snowflake db, using the `dplyr.snowflakedb` package (on GitHub). I am able to install and load the libraries, then set the classpath pointing to the latest JDBC driver (`snowflake-jdbc-3.0.9.jar`).

```
# need to load RJDBC, or error 'could not find function ".jinit"' is thrown
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr.snowflakedb)
options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "drivers/snowflake-jdbc-3.0.9.jar")
```

When trying to setup the connection object with `src_snowflakedb()`, I get the following error message (I removed the account details, but they are correct in the actual code):

```
> nike_db <- src_snowflakedb(user = "user",
                     password = "user",
                     account = "acme",
                     opts = list(warehouse = "my_wh",
                                 db = "my_db",
                                 schema = "my_schema"))
URL: jdbc:snowflake://acme.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?account=acme&warehouse=my_wh&my_db=db&schema=my_schema
Error: 'src_sql' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'
```

Indeed the current version of dplyr doesn't export nor include any `src_sql()` function:

```
> dplyr:::src_sql
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'src_sql' not found
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think that's been moved to `dbplyr` per the [cran comments](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/bad5b1057d68c0060af9d6baef6a3b1bc750cde4/cran-comments.md#reverse-dependencies). You should contact the authors to update the package for the latest dplyr release.

Comment: Or rollback your `dplyr` installation.

Comment: Thank you @mrflick indeed I opened an issue on the package repo. Not sure if it is being actively maintained though. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below sample code :

```
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-1.8\\jre")
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
install.packages(c("rJava"))
install.packages(c("RJDBC", "DBI", "dplyr"))
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("snowflakedb/dplyr-snowflakedb")
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr.snowflakedb)
options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "C:\\Driver\\snowflake-jdbc-3.11.1.jar")

my_db <- src_snowflakedb(user = "USERNAME" , password = "PASSWORD", account = "test",host = 'test.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com',opts = list(warehouse = "WAREHOUSE_NAME",db='DATABASE_NAME',schema='SCHEMA_NAME'))

tbl(my_db, "TABLE_NAME")
```

Note :

a) If your Snowflake Account URL is like "https://test.snowflakecomputing.com" use below format :

```
my_db <- src_snowflakedb(user = "USERNAME" , password = "PASSWORD", account = "test", opts = list(warehouse = "WAREHOUSE_NAME",db='DATABASE_NAME',schema='SCHEMA_NAME'))
```

b) If your Snowflake Account URL is like "https://test.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com" use below format :

```
my_db <- src_snowflakedb(user = "USERNAME" , password = "PASSWORD", account = "test", host = 'test.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com', opts = list(warehouse = "WAREHOUSE_NAME",db='DATABASE_NAME',schema='SCHEMA_NAME'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and had to go back to resort to the new version of the JDBC connection via SF: you can see link here:

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/ka131000000O5Jr/connecting-r-to-snowflake-using-the-jdbc-driver-mac-os-x

all you really need though is this:

```
result <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, "select current_timestamp() as now")
print(result)
```